# How to visit a url in internal network?

Tags: iis, networking

My laptop is serving a web page at `127.0.0.3/abc`, and I can visit it using this url on my laptop. Now my mobile phone and my laptop are using same wifi network. I can check the internal IP for my phone and my laptop. So my laptop's internal IP is `10.1.11.140`, I'm wondering how I can visit the abc page with my phone. I tried `10.1.11.140/abc` and `10.1.11.140/127.0.0.3/abc`, neither works.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you turned off your firewall or at least opened the port 80? Additionally 127.0.0.1 won't work over the network, because it's localhost only.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I have enabled 127.0.0.3

Comment: 127.0.0.0/8 are loopback addresses and just work on your machine...

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify

1. That your web server is bound to the external IP (10.1.111.140)
2. That your firewall permits access to port 80 (or whatever port you are serving your webpage)

Comment: Is `10.1.11.140/127.0.0.3/abc` the url I should be using?

Comment: I have enabled 127.0.0.3 under Inbound Rules, how do I make my web server bound to (10.1.111.140)? This IP is assigned by wifi and can change right?

Comment: You should assign your laptop a static ip address. Do this on your wireless router. Enable the firewall for this static ip and configure your webserver by running `inetmgr`. And.. this address should not start with 127...

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your laptop a static ip address. Do this on your wireless router. Enable the firewall for this static ip and configure your webserver (website binding) by running `inetmgr`. And.. this address should not start with 127...